# Decomposition an operator in terms of symmetric and anti-symmetric components

Tags: operator-theory

In linear algebra, we can write any operator as the sum of a symmetric and skew-symmetric parts:

$$A=A^{\mathrm{sym}}+A^{\mathrm{skew}}$$

where

$$A^{\mathrm{skew}}=\frac{1}{2}(A-A^T)$$

and

$$A^{\mathrm{sym}}=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$$.

Can the same be done with any general (continuous) operator?

Comment: Yes, of course. Using *adjoint* in place of transpose.

Comment: By the way, I think you got your skew and sym operators mixed up.

Comment: @Paul for what it's worth, this fails for higher order tensors. It is not the case that every tensor is expressed as a sum of a completely symmetric and completely antisymmetric tensor. One has to study representation theory to obtain a canonical decomposition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is yes.  This is a standard trick in Operator Theory.  Provided that the operator $A$ is bounded (i.e. continuous) it has a bounded adjoint $A^*$.  This would be the conjugate transpose of a matrix in finite dimensions.

We can decompose $A$ into a sum of a self adjoint operator and an anti-self adjoint operator by:

$$A = \frac{A + A^*}{2} + \frac{A - A^*}{2}.$$

This also holds for functions of a real variable in a similar way.  For instance we can write any function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as a sum of a even and odd function by:

$$f(x) = \frac{f(x) + f(-x)}{2} + \frac{f(x) - f(-x)}{2}$$

In many instances we try to draw analogies between operators and real/complex numbers.  This often happens through the spectral theorem.

Comment: What would you call the first equation ? I'd like to read up more on it. Thanks

Comment: How does this work for $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ functions?