# Matrix Properties Problem

Tags: matrices

If $A\in M(n\times n;R)$ and $K= \dfrac {A+A^T}{2} $ and $L= \dfrac{A-A^T}{2}$. Prove:
i) that $K$ and $-L$ are symmetric
ii) that $K+L=A$
iii) that $K$ and $L$ are unique matrices with the properties i and ii

I cannot prove that $-L$ is symmetric. I can only prove that $(-L)^T=L$ .
About the last question I have supposed that a pair B,C of matrices exist with the above properties but I cannot prove why this hypothesis is wrong.

Any idea?

Comment: You just happen to get wrong formulation. $L$ is *skew* symmetric, i.e. $L^T=-L$ (as you proved). About uniqueness: assume there are two such pairs, i.e. $K_1+L_1=K_2+L_2=A$, with the above properties, then what can you say about matrices $K_1-K_2$ and $L_1-L_2$?

Comment: You can take a look at this http://math.stackexchange.com/q/440861/254733

Answer (score 1):

$L$ is not symmetric.
$$
L^T = \left( \frac {A-A^T} 2 \right)^T = \frac {A^T-A} 2 = -L \ne L\text{ unless } L=0.
$$

$L$ is skew-symmetric, i.e. it satisfies $L^T=-L$.

Suppose $B$ is symmetric and $C$ is skew-symmetric and $B+C = K+L$.

Then $B-K = L-C$.  Since $B-K$ is symmetric and $L-C$ is skew-symmetric, we have a matrix $M= B-K= L-C$ that is both symmetric and skew-symmetric, so that
$$
M= M^T = -M.
$$
If $M=-M$ then $M=0$.  Thus $B-K=0$, so $B=K$.  In the same way, one can show that $L=C$.  Thus the pair $K,L$ is the *only* pair consisting of a symmetric matrix and a skew-symmetric matrix whose sum is $A$.